# 3D plot of cylindrical surface in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a cylindrical surface using matplotlib.

I don't understand why my code isn't working...

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1)

x = 10 * np.cos(u)
y = 10 * np.sin(u)
z = 10
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: First, you only create one value of `u`. Second, you don't create a surface, but only a circle of radius 10 at `z=10`. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The one is there because I got frustrated and tried putting in random numbers just to see what would happen. 

I need a pipe looking surface figure centered on the z axis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the coordinates of a two-dimensional surface to use `ax.plot_surface`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

us = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 32)
zs = np.linspace(0, 10, 2)

us, zs = np.meshgrid(us, zs)

xs = 10 * np.cos(us)
ys = 10 * np.sin(us)
ax.plot_surface(xs, ys, zs, color='b')

plt.show()
```

which produces

[image]